# Generate an arbitrary linear function in ScalaCheck?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm trying to generate an arbitrary function of the form f(x) = ax + b, where a and b are arbitrary integers, in ScalaCheck. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
def arbitraryFunction[Int] = Arbitrary { 
  for (
    a <- Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary;
    b <- Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary
  ) yield (new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(x : Int): Int = a * x + b })
}
```

but I get an error:

```
overloaded method value * with alternatives:
[error]   (x: Double)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Float)Float <and>
[error]   (x: Long)Long <and>
[error]   (x: scala.Int)scala.Int <and>
[error]   (x: Char)scala.Int <and>
[error]   (x: Short)scala.Int <and>
[error]   (x: Byte)scala.Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (Int(in method arbitraryFunction))
```

Why doesn't this work? I'm not sure why I'm getting an overloaded method error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def arbitraryFunction[Int]
```

this defines a function with a type paramter called `Int`. As far as I understand your problem, your function does not need any type parameters. The compiler error is caused by this type identifier, which shadows the "normal" `Int` identifier. Just remove it and your code will work, unless it contains other flaws.